# Doctrine: Many-To-Many Relationship with ID

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

Is it possible in a **Doctrine 2 Many-To-Many** relationship to **NOT** have a **composite key** from the join tables but rather to have **an ID column.**

**A_B**

```
ID
A_ID
B_ID
```

**Current issue** is that it orders the **inserted ids** by ascending order, but I need them to be in the order that they have been added **from the form**.

Thanks

Comment: Always a bit dubious when people want to order by primary keys.  In any event, if the default behavior does not suit then create your own join entity and establish many-to-one relations with the other two entities.  But quite frankly, if sorting of an entity is important then add your own sort column.

Comment: I would suggest adding an auto timestamp column for this and sort the results using the timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Many-to-many relations aren't meant to be ordered. If you want to order something you're introducing extra data to the joining table and it stops being a joining table but a separate entity. So in order to order the relation you'd have to define the "joining entity" and setup many-to-one realations to both tables like that:

```
Table A            Table AB            Table B
ID                 A_ID                ID
                   B_ID
                   order
```

with AB table having many-to-one relations to A and B.

Answer (score -1):

yes it is possible

```
Table A            Table AB           Table B
ID                 ID
                   A_ID                ID
                   B_ID
                   order
```

in A entity you should define:

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="\YourNameSpace\Model\Entities\B",fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
* @ORM\JoinTable(
*      name="AB",
*      joinColumns={
*          @ORM\JoinColumn(name="B_ID", referencedColumnName="A_ID")
*      },
*      inverseJoinColumns={
*          @ORM\JoinColumn(name="B_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")
*      }
*)
*/
protected $B;
```

and in B entity:

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\YourNameSpace\Model\Entities\A", inversedBy="AB", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
* @ORM\JoinColumns({
*   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="A_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")
* })
*/
protected $A;
```

but if your main problem is only sorting you can add created field to your table and sort by it.

```
->orderBy('AB.created', 'DESC')
```

Comment: At some point you should probably try what you suggested.  I suspect you will realize that Doctrine ManyToMany relations cannot have additional attributes.  Down voted accordingly.